# SMTP and Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, smtp, pickle

I am very new in Python.
While developing SMTP program with smtplib lib, some unexpected thing happended.
When I send the e-mail, the f-string does not work.
Could you tell me what is the problem?
`

```
import pickle
import smtplib
from smtplib import*
from email.mine.text import MINETEXT

def email():
    with open ("temp.txt" as 'wb') as f
    data = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1') #due to encoding issue
    (omit) #The rest works fine
    content=MINEText(f"{data}")
    (omit)

email()
```

`

I searched Google, Git and stack such a long time.
(It may be the Search Keyword problem or due to my poor English Reading Comprehension)
But, I could not get answer. When I send mail like that, I get mail written
"f"{data}"
It(temp.txt) is not empty file I had wrote some data in it.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with python, but a few points that immediately stood out to me:
1. Are you sure that your imports are correct? I'm guessing email.mine.text should be email.mime.text, and MINETEXT should be MIMETEXT.
2. It would help if you could share some sample contents of the text file you're using. Does this actually contain a binary serialized python object? If not, then I don't think pickle.load is what you want to be using here.
3. If the text file is just text, then you don't need to use the format syntax at all. Just load the file as a string and that's your content. https://sta

Comment: Thanks a lot... Thanks to your comment I solved problem!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've posted my comment as an answer. If you wouldn't mind accepting it, that would great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with python, but a few points that immediately stood out to me:

- Are you sure that your imports are correct? I'm guessing
  email.mine.text should be email.mime.text, and MINETEXT should be
  MIMETEXT.
- It would help if you could share some sample contents of the text file you're using. Does this actually contain a binary serialized
  python object? If not, then I don't think pickle.load is what you
  want to be using here.
- If the text file is just text, then you don't need to use the format syntax at all. Just load the file as a string and that's your
  content, i.e.

```
with open("temp.txt", "r") as text_file:
    data = text_file.read()
```